# Bind app scrip function to specific sheets only & exclude the rest

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am very new to app scrips and have found a code for enabling 2 way sync of a few sheets. However, I want to bind the function on the script to only a few named spreadsheets.

I am making a small database and I want to limit the use of the function to only 3 sheets - "Petty Cash Payments", "Data Base" and "Pending Checks". Currently, the function is being applied to all sheets on edit.

Below is the script i am using

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (!e) throw "Do not run manually";

  syncNonRow(e);
}

function syncNonRow(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() == "Petty Cash Payments" || r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart == 2) return;
  r.clear();
  let id = src.getRange(r.rowStart,1).getValue();
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Petty Cash Payments");
  const ids = db.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  let row = 0;
  for (row; row < ids.length; row++){
    if (ids[row][0] === id)
      break;
  }
  row++;
  db.getRange(row,r.columnStart).setValue(e.value);
}
```

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking.  What does this code currently do that you want it to do differently?

Comment: The code currently syncs data between 2 sheets - the first (Sheet - Petty Cash Payments) being the sheet where the data originally rests and the other (Sheet 2 - Database) where the same data is pulled using a query function. So if I make an edit on the Database sheet, it will show up on the Petty Cash payments sheet.

Comment: So what specifically is this function doing that you want it to do differently?  I assume this is in a Node.js environment?

Comment: This is on google sheets app script - sorry really poor on my technical knowledge here. This script is running perfectly, but the problem is it runs on all the spreadsheets on my document. I want to restrict its use on only 3 sheets that I have mentioned on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code gets the sheet with the `getActiveSheet()` method and saved that to the `src` variable.  Later on it checks `src.getName() == "Petty Cash Payments"` which is the name of one of the sheets you care about, so it's already doing a check in there.

I still do not fully understand the usage or requirements, but I **think** you can do what you want like this:

```js
function syncNonRow(e){
  //A list of sheet names that we only want tun function to run on
  const sheetsToSync = ["Petty Cash Payments", "Data Base", "Pending Checks"];
  
  //Get info about this sheet
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetName = src.getName();
  
  //Only continue if the current sheet name is in the above list
  if(sheetsToSync.includes(sheetName)){
    const r = e.range;
    if (sheetName == "Petty Cash Payments" || r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart == 2) return;
    r.clear();
    let id = src.getRange(r.rowStart,1).getValue();
    const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Petty Cash Payments");
    const ids = db.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    let row = 0;
    for (row; row < ids.length; row++){
      if (ids[row][0] === id)
        break;
    }
    row++;
    db.getRange(row,r.columnStart).setValue(e.value);
  }
}
```

Basically we just keep a list of the sheets you mentioned, and then check is the current sheet name is in that list or not.